# Any way to obtain generated id for new entity instance in HibernateInterceptor?

Tags: java, hibernate

For the sake of discussion, consider the following Hibernate annotated object:

```
@Entity
public class TestModelObject {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }    
}
```

The question is, how can you obtain the generated ID value, for a new instance, via a HibernateInterceptor (persisted via `session.save`)?  I will outline some of the methods available, which I've tested, and explain why each one is insufficient:

- [onSave](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/Interceptor.html#onSave(java.lang.Object,%20java.io.Serializable,%20java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.String[],%20org.hibernate.type.Type[])) - Does not work because id is null, for a new instance being inserted.  This makes sense because Hibernate doesn't know the ID ahead of time in this case because it's generated at insertion time by the RDBMS.
- [postFlush](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/Interceptor.html#postFlush(java.util.Iterator)) - This has the data that I'm after, but is unusable.  It contains an iterator of many objects being flushed, including the one you're interested in, but there's no reasonably simple way to pull out the newly saved instance from this iterator, without doing something terribly hackish like adding a "marker" boolean and populating it in onSave, and looking for it here.
- [instantiate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/Interceptor.html#instantiate(java.lang.String,%20org.hibernate.EntityMode,%20java.io.Serializable)) - This sort of has the data, but is unusable.  It gets called every time Hibernate instantiates an object, and it includes the id as a parameter.  It definitely gets called for a newly persisted entity, but there's no reasonable to correlate to the entity itself, since it only includes the class name, type (POJO in this case), and id.

I was hoping for something like a `postSave`, which would fire after the insert completes, for the newly created entity, that would have the generated id populated.  But I wasn't able to find such a thing.  Is there any way to accomplish what I'm trying to do, without resorting to hacks such as saving twice and performing the interceptor "work" on the second save?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [JPA Entity Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityListeners.html)?
Using *Entity Listeners* you can annotate your entity class like this:

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners({ UserEntityListener.class, UserPasswordValidator.class })
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Columnt(name = "LOGIN")
    private String login;

    @Column(name = "PASSWORD")
    private String password;

    // getters, setters ommited

}
```

Then you implement your listeners:

```
public class BookEntityListener {

    @PostPersist
    public void postPersist(User user) {
        // do your logic
    }

}

public class PasswordValidator {

    @PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    public void validatePassword(User user) {
        if (passwordTooShort(user.password())
            throw new PersistenceException("Password too short");
    }

}
```

There are multiple lifecycle annotations available:

- [`@PrePersist`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/PrePersist.html)
  Executed before the entity manager persist operation is actually
  executed or cascaded. This call is synchronous with the persist operation.
- [`@PostPersist`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/PostPersist.html)
  Executed after the entity manager persist operation is actually executed or 
  cascaded. This call is invoked after the database `INSERT` is executed.
- [`@PreRemove`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/PreRemove.html)
  Executed before the entity manager remove operation is actually executed or 
  cascaded. This call is synchronous with the remove operation.
- [`@PostRemove`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/PostRemove.html)
  Executed after the entity manager remove operation is actually
  executed or cascaded. This call is synchronous with the remove
  operation.
- [`@PreUpdate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/PreUpdate.html)
  Executed before the database `UPDATE` operation.
- [`@PostUpdate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/PostUpdate.html)
  Executed after the database `UPDATE` operation.
- [`@PostLoad`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/PreLoag.html)
  Executed after an entity has been loaded into the current
  persistence context or an entity has been refreshed.

Comment: Do you know off the top of your head whether `@PostPersist` and `@PostUpdate` fire on entities that had only a mapped collection change?  There is an [open Hibernate bug](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4897) where `onFlushDirty` isn't called in that case, and if the underlying issue affects the entity listeners as well, then I can't use them.  If you don't know, then I can test it; thanks.

Comment: However, if you have a `to-one` relation to parent mapped in your child entities, you could listen on child entities as well, and get to the parent by calling from the child.